# Share Delphi components but without source code

Tags: delphi, components

I've created some components in Delphi and I would like to give them to somebody else for use, but without source code.

I use the latest version of Delphi (10.2 Tokyo).

What are the steps I need to follow? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want them to be able to use the components in projects built with run-time packages?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share components in Delphi without source code, **you must ensure that the other user has the exact same version of Delphi as you have**<sup>[1]</sup>. This won't work with a different version. Note that it does not have to be the same SKU, i.e. you can have Professional or Community and the other can have, say, Enterprise. Only the version (e.g. Berlin 10.1, Tokyo 10.2, etc.) is important.

Then you can either

- put them in a package and distribute the *bpl* and *dcp* files.
- distribute the *dcu* files.
- or both (preferrable)

Note that the user will have to install these. There are instructions in the help files on how to do that *(no link, sorry, as the DocWiki seems to be down right now)*. Note that the package must be in one of the paths in the [Windows DLL search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

You could of course also write an installer, using one of the installer creating applications like InnoSetup *(no association)*, but that is a topic of its own.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *That is the reason that many Delphi developers prefer components or classes with source and would not accept or buy one of these without source. Having the source also allows you to fix little bugs.*

Comment: I cannot find the "bpl" file

Comment: @REALSOFO: Did you make one? See the help files on how to make one. Note that you even may have to make **two**: a designtime package an a runtime package. The design time package refers to the runtime package and is only needed to install the component in the IDE. If you installed the component, there should at least be a designtime package. The runtime package is needed at runtime, for the program to run.

Comment: FWIW, to find a file, use a tool like [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/). That will quickly find any file on your HD. *(no association, just a tool I use a lot)*.

Comment: +1 for answer. As an addition to it: the best approach to deliver non-source components to users is to have as most of recent Delphi's version installed on your machine as you can. It will allows you to compile your components for all available versions of IDE. Small remark to [1] - another reason for having source code is an ability to make hot-fix for unexpected errors\bugs\etc. in components. Not always components' provider can fix it fast on demand.